# Validate HTML5 field input without <FORM> and other server-side code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, yahoo-finance

Been fiddling around with jQuery and HTML5, but I am stuck on a simple simple action. 
JSFiddle here: http://tinyurl.com/oqmkyhr

I have a field input where I input a number, and when I press a button, the inputted number is rounded to 2 decimal places. The catch is, you cannot use  or server side code AND it is all within 1 html document.

This is what I have:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Scotiabank Currency Converter</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Converts currencies with Yahoo! Finance API">
  <meta name="author" content="Kangze Huang">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="#">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type='number' id='Amount' value='Amount convert' step='0.01'>
<input type='button' id='Validate' value='Check decimals'>
<h1></h1>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#validate').click(function(){
        $('Amount').value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
        $('h2').text(value);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

When I press the Validate button, it turns into NaN (On Chrome & other web-browsers)! On JSFiddle it does nothing. 
What am I doing wrong? Perhaps syntax or something I'm missing?

Comment: Your selector for the #Amount element is wrong. You are missing the #, it should be $("#Amount")

Comment: Can't see any code in your jsfiddle. BTW, your `$('Amount')` should be `$('#Amount')`. And I suppose your `$('h2')` should be `$('h1')` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#validate').click(function(){
   1^
    $('Amount').value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
      2^       3^                 4^
    $('h2').text(value);
      5^
```

1. `validate` is not `Validate`
2. `Amount` will match `<Amount>` elements which don't exist. ID selectors begin with a `#`
3. jQuery objects don't have value properties. DOM nodes (if they are form controls) do. You are probably looking for `val()`
4. `value` is an undefined variable. You need to define it before you use it. You probably want `$('Amount').val()` instead of using `value` at all.
5. You have no elements that match this selector, and heading elements should be used for *headings*.

So what you are probably looking for is:

```js
$('#Validate').click(function() {
  var value = $('#Amount').val();
  value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
  console.log(value);
  $('output').val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' id='Amount' value='Amount convert' step='0.01'>
<input type='button' id='Validate' value='Check decimals'>
<output></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select something by id in jquery, you need to use a `#` sign. In your case `$('#Amount')`; Also, there are no `h2` elements on your page, so `$('h2').text(value);` won't do anything. Additionally, if you want to get the value of an input in jquery, you use the `.val()` functions, and not `.value`.

Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9kqbue5t/2/

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have `$('Amount').value`. You are missing the '#' and the parenthesis and referencing the value wrong. But you have the right idea. What you can try is:

```
$('#validate').click(function(){
    var amount = $('#Amount').value();
        $('h1').text(parseFloat(value).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should be $("#Amount"). You are missing the #.

Also, if you are trying to ASSIGN the value, you should be using:

```
$("#Amount").val( parseFloat(value).toFixed(2) );
```

I am not sure where you are getting your 'value' variable from, I don't see it getting assigned anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

i see many syntax and other mistakes in your code, use the below code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Scotiabank Currency Converter</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Converts currencies with Yahoo! Finance API">
  <meta name="author" content="Kangze Huang">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="#">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type='number' id='Amount' value='Amount convert' step='0.01'>
<input type='button' id='Validate' value='Check decimals'>
<h1></h1>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#validate').click(function(){
        $('#Amount').val(parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)); //you missed # in this, normally in jquery we use .val() method to set the value of the input types
        $('h1').html(parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)); // in the above code you have used h1 so here also use h1
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```